# PDF file hyperlinks into web hyperlinks / notepad ++ replace

Tags: regex, pdf, replace, hyperlink, notepad++

Since Chrome default pdf viewer doesn't display relative hyperlinks in pdf's files I try to find a semi-automate way to replace them with links to the specific path on a server.

Upon opening pdf in a notepad++ i found quite interesting syntax of a pdf file. Anyway, replacing the path itself was quite easy using regular expressions in notepad.

The problem occurred when trying to get rid of this structure:

`706 0 obj
<</F 707 0 R/S/Launch>>
endobj`

since notepad replace do not work with multi-line expressions.

I can delete them separately:

`([0-9]+\s[0-9]\s)obj$
(\W+)F(\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]\s)R(\W)S(\W)Launch(\W+)$
endobj$`

but then I mess with other objects that I do not want to change, so I need a way to delete it as a whole.

Any idea, or maybe there is a simple way to convert File-objects in pdf to the source ones or a different text editor that allows to search for Multi-line expressions with advanced modifiers.

Comment: Does `_this structure_` extend over multiple lines? If so, where are the line-breaks?

Comment: Things that match newlines (possible line-breaks) in your regex are `\s` and `\W`, not sure what $ is trying to match (since its NP++)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. TheStucture extends over 3 multiple lines (as presented in question) with a CR as line break. Unfortunately \W as a line break does not work for me? Why is that? Tried regex suggested by Jerry, notepad couldn't find anything.

Comment: I asume the non-word character class is denoted by `\W`. Not sure what you mean about `\W` as CR is one of the many charcters that is matched by that class. And not sure of NP++ if it feeds multiple lines to regexes or not. Did Jerry's work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this perhaps, if you still want to do it with N++:

```
[0-9]+\s[0-9]\sobj\s*\W+F\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]\sR\WS\WLaunch\W+\s*endobj$
```

I basically copy/pasted your regex, removed unnecessary groupings and replaced the middle `$` with `\s*`. (`\s` matches whitespaces, horizontal tabs, newlines, carriage returns and formfeeds, so it will go 'multiline' if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against modifying PDF files this way, unless you really know what you are doing.
PDF files are binary files, and they contain several pieces of information that are based on byte-counts starting from the beginning of the file or an object (xref table, compressed streams, encrypted files, etc).

Modifying a PDF file without taking its structure into account will corrupt the file in most cases. PDF readers may in general be able to recover from this type of errors, but it is always possible that you may break a file beyond repair.

There are two possible ways to reduce the chances of corrupting your files (it may still happen if you are not careful):

- Modify your files with a PDF processing library that allows you to manipulate the dictionaries directly and resave.
- If you still want to modify them manually, then at least make sure that the byte-count of every modified object (also called PDF dictionary) does not change. For example you can try replacing valid characters inside a PDF dictionary with spaces, or you can replace (optional) indirect references like 6 0 R with a null value 0 0 R (also replacing digits with spaces with needed).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, to be honest I have no knowledge about PDF format, good to know that I can mess up it's structure. Is it possible that I do some changes in pdf code and It works fine on my machine but might not work for someone else?

Comment: I would rather say that it depends on the file, not on the machine. Depending on how complex your files are, some files may work and some others may not.

Comment: It also depends on the PDF viewer you are using, since you are basically relying on the ability of the PDF viewer to handle corrupt files. Note that if this ever stops working, you will not be able to report it as a bug on the viewer, since it was never supposed to work in the first place.